# Is there a way to pass in query parameters to mysql test containers

Tags: java, mysql, testing, jdbc, containers

I am currently testing my application using the JDBC test containers. I am having issues with timezones and setting certain query parameters with my test containers that I can with my normal mysql container.

Here is an example of my spring.datasource.url that I am using for my test container - jdbc:tc:mysql:5.7://database/myDb?useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=Australia/Melbourne

Howevervdebugging through the code, it semes like the query parameters does get parsed but it doesn't get used at all by the test container. Is there anyway I can set these variables with my test containers?

I tried passing in a container parameter in the form of a my_sql.conf file which sets trys to set the useLegacyDatetimeCode but that didn't work as I believe it doesn't recognize the value

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Thank you for your question. However it seems like you are not familiar with the guide of Stackoverflow to [How To: Ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Please read it and adjust your question accordingly by using the Edit option.